How to conditionally execute a command based on passed argument
I have app MyApp which is an Angular app but it has to be wrapped into a .war archive MyApp.war since I have to deploy it to Liberty server.
I have exec-maven-plugin set as below with exec goal to run npm install command
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>npm-install</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>npm</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>install</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    ...

With this configuration of exec-maven-plugin, the npm-install execution will run npm install and will ALWAYS install ALL dependencies specified in package.json.
I want to omit installing dependencies specified in optionalDependencies section of package.json if an EnvName argument is passed to exec-maven-plugin.
QUESTION: How do I make the exem-maven-plugin npm-install execution receive an argument named EnvName and if EnvName is equal to test, execute npm install --include=optional and if EnvName is not equal to test execute npm install --omit=optional?
I have tried modifying the exec-maven-plugin configuration like below,  and that would execute fine but would not install optional dependencies regardless what I pass as EnvName.
<arguments>
   <argument>install</argument>
   <argument>
     <!-- If EnvName is 'test', include optional dependencies -->
     ${EnvName.equals('test') ? '--include=optional' : '--omit=optional'}
   </argument>
</arguments>


Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].
